# Using curves how do i generate a grid of 1m x 1m sections with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I have converted a mesh to curves and with geometry nodes, how can i create a grid in 1m x 1m sections or 1m by 2m for example?

[image: 1m x 1m grid of faces]

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you first make the "grid", then convert it into curves like this for example

[image]

Comment: ah i totally see where i was going wrong, it does make much more sense to do it that way thank you :)
Maybe i should ask this in a new question? But out of interest if a mesh i have is rotated on the z axis by any degree and i have applied the scale is there a way to use this method also. Im not sure if there is a way to know the rotation of the mesh off the grid?